# Hibernate where to put classname.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

My friend Google told me I should put the classname.hbm.xml to where classname.java stays at.
But it doesn't work, saying

> **resource: AccountsRequest.hbm.xml not found**

AccountsRequest is the java class name. I use javac to compile. Not sure if it is the reason. AccountsRequest.java is at /WEB-INF/src/.

**EDITED**: in hibernate.cfg.xml i have

> resource="AccountsRequest.hbm.xml"/>

hibernate.cfg.xml is at /WEB-INF/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put it in the runtime classpath. The `/WEB-INF/classes` is covered by the webapp's default runtime classpath. So it should end up there.

However, if you're using an IDE, you can also drop them in `src` folder of the project (no, **not** `/WEB-INF/src`!), a bit decent IDE will then automagically put it in `/WEB-INF/classes` during build.